# PHP JSON array multi-element parsing

Tags: php, json

I have an API JSON element that returns an array with some of the following:

```
Array(    
[page] => 1    
[perPage] => 25    
[totalResults] => 161    
[totalPages] => 7    
[results] => Array of interesting information
```

I know how to query [GET] individual pages and can easily parse the 25 [results] and access the interesting information on the [page]. However, if I don't specify the [page] in the query I still get the full results starting at [page] => 1.

My question is there a way to iterate from [page] => 1 to [page] => 7 while iterating through each [results] similar to the code example below?

i.e. this is only valid for a page,

```
// Display the results we are after
for ($x=0; $x < $json[perPage]; $x++) {
    echo $json[results][$x][title] .'<br>';
    echo $json[results][$x][start] .'<br>';
}
```

*edit*
I can do the cURL with multiple options for the API, one of which is specifying which specific page to return in the JSON or just to accept what it returns by default.
    `CURLOPT_URL => $communityUrl . 'api/calendar/events' . '?sortBy=title',`
or
    `CURLOPT_URL => $communityUrl . 'api/calendar/events' . '?sortBy=title&page=2',`

I think we are close, but just missing some aspect, though I'm not sure what. Somehow $json[page] needs to be iterated while we go through the $json[results]. I'm still experimenting with other combinations.

Comment: `don't specify the [page]` and then apply foreach and get all interactive data of all pages

Comment: I can do the cURL with multiple options for the API, one of which is specifying which specific page to return in the JSON or just to accept what it returns by default.
`CURLOPT_URL => $communityUrl . 'api/calendar/events' . '?sortBy=title',`
or
`CURLOPT_URL => $communityUrl . 'api/calendar/events' . '?sortBy=title&page=2',`

I think we are close, but just missing some aspect, though I'm not sure what. Somehow $json[page] needs to be iterated while we go through the $json[results]. I'm still experimenting with other combinations.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

what you have to do is:-

1.don't specify the [page] so that all pages data come inside single-array

2.Apply `foreach()` two iterate over the array

3.Get desired data

```
foreach($json as $js){
    foreach($json[results] as $jr){
        echo $jr[title] .'<br>';
        echo $jr[start] .'<br>';
    }
}
```

Comment: Awesome. Thank you! It performed exactly as desired. Now to bone up on foreach! Thank you again!

Comment: @Kodiak  glad to help you ):)

Comment: -Update- Initially I thought it had done what I needed however it did not iterate through the seven pages, but just 5 times through the first page, thus causing 5x copies of what was being done. I'll add more details momentarily to help clarify.

Answer (score 0):

For this particular REST API, one has to query the API changing the page each time. There is no full query dump of all events.